# I'm confused about the tools/frameworks for mobile web app development

Tags: titanium, extjs, cappuccino

I'm confused. What are the differences between Sencha, Titanium, and Cappuccino?

Answer (score 2):

(I'm assuming you're talking about Appcelerator Titanium.)

Probably the biggest difference is the language used. Cappuccino uses a language called Objective-J, which is VERY similar to the Objective-C language used for native Mac and iPhone/iPad apps, but then gets compiled into Javascript for a web app. The other two use HTML/JS like a native web app.

Also, there's the big question of what the application actually looks like on a mobile platform, and what features it can access. Cappuccino and Sencha, AFAIK, allow you to design web apps that are optimized for mobile. But, since they're just glorified web pages, they won't be able to get things like accelerometer or GPS data; they aren't native iPhone or Android apps. Titanium, however, compiles to a native iPhone or Android app and allows you to do those things. Titanium can also compile to a native desktop application.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

1. Sencha is the web-based **javascript** framework to develop webapp. You must use Sencha with other platform such as [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) in order to run this webapp in iPhone / Android. There are many web-based javascript framework like Sencha such as [jQuery Mobile](http://www.jquerymobile.com/), [Magic Framework](http://www.jeffmcfadden.com/projects/Magic%20Framework/), [xUI](http://xuijs.com/)...
2. Titanium is different. It also use Javascript for develop app. But Titanium will compile these javascript to objective-C code. It mean when using Titanium, you develop **native** app, not webapp as PhoneGap.